# Bloc: how to mock the get state

Tags: flutter, mocking, state, bloc

This  is my test:

```
 MockBloc bloc = MockBloc();
        when (bloc.state).thenAnswer((_) => State)
```

I want to give a specific state, but, if I try to simply write `MyState()` there, the IDE will just say

> isn't a Stream< blocState >

How can I pass the `State`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your mock return a stream of states, not state object.

```
final controller = StreamController<BlocState>();
when(bloc.state).thenAnswer((_) => controller.stream);
```

Then you can add new states to controller

```
controller.add(MyState());
```